# How to create input only control in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the following, but without surrounding div required by ReactJS:

```
render() {
    return (<div><input type="text" /></div>)
}
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html uncontrolled components or no?

Comment: Why do you think the surrounding `div` is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

surrounding div is not required

```
render() {
  return (<input type="text" />);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davinel/aw32n4kr/1/